# Find Embed Code for Video

Tags: html, video, youtube, embed, blogger

I am attempting to find the embed code for the video on this site:

http://beyondbinaries1.blogspot.com/2007/12/family-stone-dinner-scene.html

I would like to place it into a PowerPoint slide.

I have opened up Chrome Developer to take a better look at the coding behind it, and this is the coding that I get:

```
<embed src="//www.youtube.com/get_player" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="320" height="266" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" flashvars="flvurl=http://redirector.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?id%3D4c781227fbfdc727%26itag%3D5%26source%3Dblogger%26app%3Dblogger%26cmo%3Dsensitive_content%253Dyes%26ip%3D0.0.0.0%26ipbits%3D0%26expire%3D1451749858%26sparams%3Did,itag,source,ip,ipbits,expire%26signature%3D93CE2FD2A65DB68E8F19A0A60B8DCCD85E8E00C3.76ECE06C0E2070E55D3FB6C98A830F69A87EFFF6%26key%3Dck2&amp;iurl=http://video.google.com/ThumbnailServer2?app%3Dblogger%26contentid%3D4c781227fbfdc727%26offsetms%3D5000%26itag%3Dw160%26sigh%3DqZuEv17IBU1O_mOsOoReqcCPqcw&amp;autoplay=0&amp;ps=blogger" allowfullscreen="true">
```

I have done a little more research and see it is because the video was uploaded by the user and with Google also being YouTube, it appears as a YouTube video even though it was not actually uploaded to YouTube.  [Source](http://blogger-hints-and-tips.blogspot.com/2012/07/google-video-being-retired-impact-for.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can't 
because this is not a youtube video, this video was uploaded to blogger and not youtube it appears as a youtube video because blogger is using youtube's player

but you can download or embed it from this link

http://r5---sn-4g5edn7s.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?id=4c781227fbfdc727&itag=5&source=blogger&app=blogger&ip=197.35.108.154&ipbits=0&expire=1453742996&sparams=expire,hvs,id,ip,ipbits,itag,mm,mn,ms,mv,nh,pl,source&signature=3DA7E51997E4A0B49B89E6D2260FBFB6A2A08CF6.6E3390B07BF6AE9D26668D9B8B4715ACBEAB54B6&key=cms1&pl=19&redirect_counter=1&req_id=c22a9cedcfa8a3ee&cms_redirect=yes&hvs=yes&mm=34&mn=sn-4g5edn7s&ms=ltu&mt=1451596516&mv=m&nh=IgpwcjAyLmZyYTAzKgkxMjcuMC4wLjE